# PHP Version Doesn't Change After Adding AddHandler

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to get one of my sites on my server to use PHP 7.3. I have added this to my .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .php
```

It is the only line in that file.  My directives of the root of the site look like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dev">
allow from all
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Whenever I run my phpInfo script, it is still reporting PHP 7.0.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you describe an action? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/handler.html

Comment: I did not add an action - didn't come up in my research.  I'm not sure how to define the action.  I tried Action application/x-httpd-php73 /usr/bin/php7.3 but Apache reported "Invalid command 'Action', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration".